# Where does glassfish save your class/project after deployment on Windows?

Tags: windows, deployment, netbeans, glassfish-3

I am using Glassfish3.1 on Windows XP. After deploy a web service project using Netbeans, it works fine. But when i go to

```
install-path\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications
```

I don't see my application.

under `install\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\__internal`, there's a folder with the same name as my project. But that folder is empty.

But if i deploy a project on linux, i can find my application and classes under `application` folder.

So where are they on windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use netbeans, the default deployment dir is the *build/web* subdir of your netbeans project folder. E.g. when your project is called *myProject*, the deployment dir is *myProject/build/web*.

It's of course a bit irritating since it is usually outside the glassfish install dir. But you can configure your webapp to be based in any dir of your harddrive.

In general you can find the location of any of your glassfish webapps in the *domain.xml* file of your domain, e.g. *glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml*

Each webapp has an `<application>` element with an attribute `location`, e.g. for one of my projects:

```
<application context-root="/MyFirstWebService"
     location="file:/C:/.../NetBeansProjects/MyFirstWebService/build/web/" 
     directory-deployed="true" name="MyFirstWebService" object-type="user">
```

Answer (score 4):

you can see path of application where it was deployed through glashfish admin console

eg.

```
http://localhost:4848/
```

or

```
http://yourhost_name:4848/
```

Common Tasks -> Applications -> you_application -> general -> Location:

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `install-path\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy`

Answer (score 0):

The location of your deployed project is dependent on the IDE you use.
To detect the location. Do the following:

1. Launch your Glassfish or Payara server from this location: http://localhost:4848 or any other location of your configuration for glassfish or payara server.
2. Location the sidebar "Common Tasks"
3. Click on Applications. List of deployed application will drop down
4. Select you application from the list. Information about your app will display on the right hand side. Check for the Label "Location". e.g :  Location:

file:/C:/Users/Abode/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ImageJavapoint/build/web/

Then you will find where your app is being deployed.