# Glassfish not running web application independently of Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans-7, glassfish-4.1

Please see the steps I have followed below:

1) Start the Glassfish server in Netbeans:

[image]

2) Run the Netbeans project, which successfully browses to: http://localhost:8080/CRUDWebAppSQL/StudentServlet  I am able to use the application.
    3) Close Netbeans, which stops Glassfish (in preparation for the next step)

Then I try this:

1) Run the following DOS commands:

```
cd C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\bin
sadmin start-domain domain1
```

2) Message received saying server has started.  Browse to: http://localhost:4848/ and login.  Make sure that CRUDWebAppSQL is listed as an app.
3) Browse to: http://localhost:8080/CRUDWebAppSQL/StudentServlet which display a Glassfish 404 error

Why does step three produce a Glassfish 404 error? Does it have something to do with this: [Where does glassfish save your class/project after deployment on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515327/where-does-glassfish-save-your-class-project-after-deployment-on-windows)

Comment: Look at the logs and if you see deployment or server configuration problems you can fix them using GlassFish admin console that you are already using on port 4848

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Glassfish application in web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870069/launch-glassfish-application-in-web-browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBeans is using a different mechanism to deploy your application to support hot deployment in comparison to a manual deployment.

To run the application without NetBeans first build the web application with e.g. with Maven `mvn clean install` to get the *.war file.

Start the Glassfish application server and either deploy the war file through the web interface or with command line `asadmin deploy war-name`

By the way I would suggest to update NetBeans to the current 8.2 release and have a look at Payara, which is a patched drop-in replacement for Glassfish: http://www.payara.fish/downloads

Comment: Thanks.  That has cleared that up +1.  What happens if you deploy an app to a Glassfish server using cold deployment when it is also used as hot deployment (same app)?

Comment: It may fail due to inconsistent state, but you can use the "force redeploy" flag to overwrite the existing deployment.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you able to answer my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793208/run-enterprise-application-client-outside-netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans glassfirsh server combine with Felix platform.

Download GlassFish Server Open Source Edition. 
Unzip it and goto bin folder in the unzipped folder.
double click asadmin.bat
type `start-domain`

in this command you can start glassfirsh server
(you can find more command in google)

open browser and type `http://localhost:8080/`

click link as

> go to the Administration Console.

it view "GlassFish Console".

in here you can deploy your web app.(Extension ".war" file)